# Storing complex time intervals in database

Tags: python, django, postgresql, datetime, calendar

I'm developing application which works with events. (language: Python 2.7, RDBMS: PostgreSQL, CSM: Django 1.9.6). I need to store information about calendar events. They have highly customizable time intervals (e.g.: repeat 5 times from 5th March at 5:00 AM with duration 45 minutes, every Thursday; or repeat every odd day of month at 6:00 PM with duration 1 day and 2 hours (from 1th 6:00 PM to 2th 8:00 PM, then from 3th 6:00 PM to 4th 8:00 PM)).

The problem is how to store such kind of information, and to do a fast selection of actual events (active at the current and specific moment in future) ?

As a workaround: use RRule and make regular job to calculate time intervals for each event for next day. But, I think it's very time-consuming operation, especially if there are thousands of events on the server (caching helps, but what to do when I need active events for the specific moment in future and it's usual query).

Comment: Does each set of intervals have a sensible termination? PostgreSQL's maximum timestamp is in 294276 AD.

Comment: "I think it's very time-consuming operation" - premature optimization is dumb. "billions of events" are you building a calendar for everyone on earth?

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' Thanks for your comment. Yes, it has sensible termination. Average time limits (start time of the first repetition and end time of the last repetition) for event will be about ten month.

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan Thanks for your comment. I agree that billions are really too much. What I want to say : event has complex time pattern, how to handle it in efficient way? Every user is able to retrieve all events active in the current moment. Caching time calculations for near future (several days) solves this problem. But when users want to retrieve all events active in specific time I really don`t know what to do. Generating all time intervals for every event at creation, produces new problems:  
1. editing time pattern in future  
2. frequently repeated events produce a lot of garbage data

Comment: @AntonPererva use materialized views. try different time windows, for example +-30 days or +-365 days. prototype it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would keep two models - one for describing the recurring rules, and one for the actual occurrences (each rule can have multiple occurrences, but not an infinite number since you stated that they have "sensible termination").

```
class Rule(models.Model):
    start = models.DateTimeField()
    end = models.DateTimeField()
    frequency = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=FREQUENCIES)
    interval = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    duration = models.PositiveIntegerField() # duration may be in seconds or minutes?
    # and so on, add all the fields you need to define the rule

class Occurrence(models.Model):
    rule = models.ForeignKey(Rule)
    start = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)
    end = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)
```

Given an instance of a Rule, you can use *rrule* from python-dateutil to generate all its Occurrences and save them to the database. Sure, there will be lots of them but these are small, simple records that the database will have no problem handling efficiently. So now the problem of finding all Occurrences that are currently active is trivial:

```
Occurrence.objects.filter(start__lte=d, end__gte=d)
```

And if you want the Rule instances instead of the Occurrences:

```
Rule.objects.filter(occurrence__start__lte=d, occurrence__end__gte=d)
```